# NullPointerException while attempting to invoke fragment interface method

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm trying to send some data to my Activity from Fragment by creating interface.

So First I created an Interface in my Fragment Class,

```
public interface OnMediaSelected{
        public void onItemPicked(String url, String type);

    }
```

Then initialized the callback variable at onAttach method,

```
   @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        callback = (OnMediaSelected) activity;
    }
```

And in another method I called my Interface callback,

```
public void Action(String url,String type){
    Log.i("data check",url);
    try {
        callback.onItemPicked(url,type);
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.i("Error",e.toString());

    }
}
```

None of those data (url, type) are null.

But when I run this app, I'm getting this error

```
Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.buckydroid.app.MoreOptions$OnMediaSelected.onItemPicked(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Is your activity implementing the interface?

Comment: Put activity and fragment code if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using a different onAttach method. Try with this one (look at the parameter):

```
@Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnMediaSelected) {
            callback = (OnMediaSelected) context;
        }
    }
```

You should change onDettach too.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void Action(String url,String type){
    Log.i("data check",url);
    try {
        ((OnMediaSelected)getActivity()).onItemPicked(url,type);
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.i("Error",e.toString());
    }
}
```

and you need to implement `OnMediaSelected` interface in your activity